How to create sticky table headers in a Nuxt UI Table Component?
I am trying to create "sticky table headers" so that way when the user scrolls a long list of table data rows, the headers stick to the top and visible in the viewport and keep the user informed of what the columns are.
I am using NuxtUI Table component in Nuxt3 and can not figure out how to get the headers to stick to the top. I tried doing the following:
  <section class="relative">
  <UTable
    :ui="{ th: { base: 'sticky top-0' } }"
    :columns="columns"
    :rows="people"
  />
  </section>

But, that did not work.
Here's my reproduction link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-ui-hg5dsj?file=app.vue
Anyone got a solution?

Your wrapper has overflow-x-auto - this means that th cannot be sticky relative to body. Change the ui:
<UTable
  :ui="{
    th: { base: 'sticky top-0' },
    wrapper: { base: '' },
  }"
  :columns="columns"
  :rows="people"
/>


Thanks, although it does stick the header to the top, now I have a problem with the long table data overflowing outside (due to overflow-x-auto being removed) the container.
